# Merging two arrayLists into a new arrayList, with no duplicates and in order, in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to "combine" two arrayLists, producing a new arrayList that contains all the numbers in the two combined arrayLists, but without any duplicate elements and they should be in order. I came up with this code below. I run through it and it makes sense to me, but Im not sure if I can be using < or > to compare get(i)'s in arrayLists. I am adding all the elements in array1 into the plusArray. Then I am going through the plusArray and comparing it to array2 to see if any of array2's elements exist inside plusArray. If they do I am doing nothing, but if they dont then I am trying to add it in its correct position. Perhaps my nested for loops being used incorrectly? Note: The ArrayLists are presorted by the user in  increasing order.

```
     ArrayList<Integer> plusArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++){
    plusArray.add(array1.get(i));
}

for(int i = 0; i < plusArray.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++){

    if(array2.get(j) < plusArray.get(i)){
        plusArray.add(i,array2.get(j));
    }
    else if(plusArray.get(i).equals(array2.get(j))){
        ;
    }
    else if(array2.get(j) > plusArray.get(i)){
        plusArray.add(i, array2.get(j));
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I dont get the exception below anymore. Instead it seems the program runs forever. I changed the location of where to add the elements in the < and > conditions.
///
Here is the exception that I get when my array lists are:
IntSet 1: { 1 2 }
IntSet 2: { 1 3 4 }

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
at IntSet.plus(IntSet.java:92)
at IntSetDriver.main(IntSetDriver.java:61)
```

Comment: Please post the exception that you get.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Instead of the code you wrote, you may use `ArrayList.addAll()` to merge the lists, `Collections.sort()` to sort it and finally traverse of the resulting ArrayList to remove duplicates. The aggregate complexity is thus `O(n)+O(n*log(n))+O(n)` which is equivalent to `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: I think this answer is kinda misreading as whole algorithm doesn't finish in O(n).

Sorting may take O(nlogn). Additionally, even if Traversal is O(n), deletion from ArrayList may take O(n) as it requires copy of (at most)  n element.

Answer (score 84):

Firstly remove duplicates:

```
arrayList1.removeAll(arrayList2);
```

Then merge two arrayList:

```
arrayList1.addAll(arrayList2);
```

Lastly, sort your arrayList if you wish:

```
collections.sort(arrayList1);
```

In case you don't want to make any changes on the existing list, first create their backup lists:

```
arrayList1Backup = new ArrayList(arrayList1);
```

Comment: if anyone finds this not working, note that the objects in list should override equals method for this to work, because -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/35960394/441902

Answer (score 16):

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();

    listA.add("A");
    listA.add("B");

List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();

    listB.add("B");
    listB.add("C");

Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>(listA);

    newSet.addAll(listB);
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(newSet);

System.out.println("New List :"+newList);
```

is giving you
 **New List :[A, B, C]**

Answer (score 14):

Java 8 `Stream API` can be used for the purpose,

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("A");
list1.add("B");
list1.add("A");
list1.add("D");
list1.add("G");

ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list2.add("B");
list2.add("D");
list2.add("E");
list2.add("G");

List<String> noDup = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
noDup.forEach(System.out::println);
```

En passant, it shouldn't be forgetten that `distinct()` makes use of `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 13):

Add ArrayList1, ArrayList2 and produce a Single arraylist ArrayList3.
Now convert it into

```
Set Unique_set = new HashSet(Arraylist3);
```

in the unique set you will get the unique elements.

**Note**

**ArrayList** allows to duplicate values.
**Set** doesn't allow the values to duplicate.
Hope your problem solves.

Comment: Try to learn Java Collections it will solve most of your needs.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one solution using java 8:

```
Stream.of(list1, list2)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .distinct()
    // .sorted() uncomment if you want sorted list
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

**Add elements in first arraylist**

```
ArrayList<String> firstArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

firstArrayList.add("A");
firstArrayList.add("B");
firstArrayList.add("C");
firstArrayList.add("D");
firstArrayList.add("E");
```

**Add elements in second arraylist**

```
ArrayList<String> secondArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

secondArrayList.add("B");
secondArrayList.add("D");
secondArrayList.add("F");
secondArrayList.add("G");
```

**Add first arraylist's elements in second arraylist**

```
secondArrayList.addAll(firstArrayList);
```

**Assign new combine arraylist and add all elements from both arraylists**

```
ArrayList<String> comboArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(firstArrayList);
comboArrayList.addAll(secondArrayList);
```

**Assign new Set for remove duplicate entries from arraylist**

```
Set<String> setList = new LinkedHashSet<String>(comboArrayList);
comboArrayList.clear();
comboArrayList.addAll(setList);
```

**Sorting arraylist**

```
Collections.sort(comboArrayList);
```

**Output**

```
 A
 B
 C
 D
 E
 F
 G
```

Answer (score 4):

> Perhaps my nested for loops being used incorrectly?

Hint:  nested loops won't work for this problem.  A simple for loop won't work either.

You need to visualize the problem.

Write two ordered lists on a piece of paper, and using two fingers to point the elements of the respective lists, step through them as you do the merge in your head.  Then translate your mental decision process into an algorithm and then code.

The optimal solution makes a single pass through the two lists.

Comment: so ur saying like a while loop or do loop? arent those the same as for loops in a different format

Comment: alright... maybe ill look at this again tomorrow and things will come more clearly.

Comment: Any more hints? I keep comming back to my original solution I thought would work

Answer (score 2):

Your second for loop should have j++ instead of i++

Comment: I fixed it and put in the new exception

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your current code is failing (what is the Exception you get?), but I would like to point out this approach performs O(N-squared).  Consider pre-sorting your input arrays (if they are not defined to be pre-sorted) and merging the sorted arrays:

http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Merge/Sorted_arrays

Sorting is generally O(N logN) and the merge is O(m+n).

Comment: Im not sure if I should be using this approach as I havent learned this yet in class. I guess it wouldnt hurt though?

Comment: If the instructor has taught a specific approach you probably want to at least implement what he has shown.  It is very important, though, to be familiar with the concept of big-O and the relative performance of different algorithms.  If you have time, implement this approach as well and compare performance for fairly large inputs.

Comment: Well he didnt really teach us how to do this. They just teach us the code and we have to implement what we know to get it done. Idk

Answer (score 1):

your nested for loop

```
 for(int j = 0; j < array2.size(); i++){
```

is infinite as j will always equal to zero, on the other hand, i will be increased at will in this loop. You get OutOfBoundaryException when i is larger than plusArray.size()

Comment: ArrayList.add(x) adds x at the end of the List, so you were not sorting the ArrayList, yet your loop needs the plusArray sorted,right?

Comment: Java API Collections and ArrayList:                      http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/

Comment: ah i see. I changed the code and added where to add the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to handcode this. The problem definition is precisely the behavior of Apache Commons [CollectionUtils#collate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#collate%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29). It's also overloaded for different sort orders and allowing duplicates.

Comment: The top answer has exactly the same form as this: "don't write it yourself, here are objects that will do it for you." I edited my phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Add elements in Final arraylist,**
**This will Help you sure**

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NonDuplicateList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    l1.add("1");l1.add("2");l1.add("3");l1.add("4");l1.add("5");l1.add("6");
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    l2.add("1");l2.add("7");l2.add("8");l2.add("9");l2.add("10");l2.add("3");
    List<String> l3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    l3.addAll(l1);
    l3.addAll(l2);
    for (int i = 0; i < l3.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j < l3.size(); j++) {
             if(l3.get(i) == l3.get(j)) {
                 l3.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(l3);
}
```

}

Output : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: Do not just dump the code. Please care to explain why this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I got your point that you don't wanna use the built-in functions for merging or remove duplicates from the ArrayList.
Your first code is running forever because the outer for loop condition is 'Always True'. 
Since you are adding elements to plusArray, so the size of the plusArray is increasing with every addition and hence 'i' is always less than it. As a result the condition never fails and the program runs forever.
Tip: Try to first merge the list and then from the merged list remove the duplicate elements. :)