# How to combine two list (or two any other kind of collections)

Tags: java, collections

I have the class `ViewPartner.java`. The class looks like the following

```
public class ViewPartner {
    private Integer id;
    //GET, SET
    //Other properties
}
```

I have two `List<ViewPartner>`, say `lst1` and `lst2` and I need to combine ones in the following way:
If there's a `ViewPartner` with the same `id` in both `lst1` and `lst2` we're putting the `ViewPartner` from `lst1`, and from both two lists otherwise.

I'm using `apache commons` and `google guava`... maybe there's some instant method?

It's not important to me to use strictly `List` here.

Comment: Kindly check out the following post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917787/merging-two-arraylists-into-a-new-arraylist-with-no-duplicates-and-in-order-in

Comment: @ChetterHummin Nice idea to convert it to a Set.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a list of unique items like this:

```
Set<ViewPartner> union = new HashSet<ViewPartner>( list1 );
union.addAll( list2 );
```

Collection(Set) `union` will now have unique items from both lists since `Set` doesn't allow the duplicate values.

besides you need to implement `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()` methods in `ViewPartner` class for member `id`.

Comment: You don't need to wrap list2 in a set: just `union.addAll(list2);` - addAll accepts Collection

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do it like this:

```
for (final ViewPartner viewPartner : lst2) {
    if (!containsViewPartnerWithId(lst1, viewPartner.getId())) {
        lst1.add(viewParner);
    }
}
//...
private boolean containsViewPartnerWithId(final List<ViewPartner> list, final Integer id) {
    for (final ViewPartner viewPartner : list) {
        if (id.equals(viewPartner.getId())) {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The reason I would not use equals/hashcode in this instance is that you want to check on id, and if that is something is set by for instance the database, then objects that are not yet assigned an id will be considered equal, which is probably not the behaviour that one would wish. Also, with todays computers, iterating is really fast, so unless your two lists are very large, performance wont be a an issue.