# How to associate two ArrayLists of objects?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, arraylist

Let's say I've got this two `ArrayLists`, the first one is of the type `ObjectA`, the second `ObjectB`.

These are ObjectA's variables:

```
 int id;
 double value;
```

And these are ObjectB's variables:

```
 int objAId;
 double disccountValue;
```

How can I retrieve the `disccountValue` of ObjectB where `objAId` is the same of the item on the first list? Just like in a SQL query, but in `ArrayLists`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two arrayLists into a new arrayList, with no duplicates and in order, in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917787/merging-two-arraylists-into-a-new-arraylist-with-no-duplicates-and-in-order-in)

Comment: You can override the equals method, and get the object index that contains the value.
ifContains() and indexOf()

Comment: One solution is to do a linear search in `listA` based on a given `objAId` from an `ObjectB`. If you sort `listA` by the `id` value, you can improve the speed by doing a binary search instead.

Comment: Similarly if you want to search for something in `listB`, you can do either a linear or binary search depending on whether you sort the list before searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the value for each object A:

```
for(ObjectA objA : arrayListOfObjectAs){
    int id = objA.id;
    for(ObjectB objB : arrayListOfObjectBs){
        if(id == objB.objAId){
            //do what you want with the objB.discountValue here
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're only looking for a single id you can get rid of that outer for loop