# ArrayList removeAll() not removing objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the simple ArrayLists of the member class:

```
ArrayList<Member> mGroupMembers = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Member> mFriends = new ArrayList<>();
```

Member class:

```
public class Member {
    private String userUID;
    private String userName;

    public String getUserUID() {
        return userUID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setUserUID(String userUID) {
        this.userUID = userUID;
    }


}
```

The ArrayList for friends contains all the users friends. What I simply wish to do is remove from the friends list, group members if present with:

```
mFriends.removeAll(mGroupMembers);
```

Yet it does nothing to the `mFriends` list...

Looking at the log statements, the friend does in fact appear within the `mGroupMember` list.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Since I don't see overriding of `equals` method in `Member` class I suspect that your lists doesn't contain same objects but only similar ones (with similar states).

Comment: You haven't included enough information in your question, but at a guess, you have different (but equivalent) `Member` objects in the lists. As Pshemo said, since you haven't defined `equals` for `Member`, it will use `Object`'s `equals`, which won't be true for equivalent `Member` objects. You need to override `equals` (and thus also `hashCode`).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How are 2 members determined to be equal?  I'm guessing if they have the same ID, you deem them equal, however java wants them to be the exact same reference in memory which may not be the case.  To correct for this you can override the `equals` function to have it return if the ids are equal:

```
public class Member {
    //..

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (!(anObject instanceof Member)) {
            return false;
        }
        Member otherMember = (Member)anObject;
        return otherMember.getUserUID().equals(getUserUID());
    }
}
```

Also when you override `.equals` it is recommended to also override `hashCode` so that the objects also work correctly in hashing functions like `Set` or `Map`.

Comment: Is the equals overridden within the Member object?

Comment: @TJCrowder also, do not forget to check if `anObject` is an instance of the class.

Comment: @Sauron yes it would be overridden in your `Member` class.  Also notice the edit, since userID is a string, it needs to be `.equals`. and not `==`.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia, Yes this is what I was forgetting.

Comment: @KevinDiTragila No need to check if it's null. `instanceof` always gives false when a null is giving to it.

Answer (score 10):

You have to understand the sequence of invocation underneath it

```
 -> ArrayList#removeAll(Collection)
 |
 | calls
 |  
 |--> ArrayList#contains(Object)
   |
   | calls
   |
   |--> ArrayList#indexOf(Object)
     |
     | calls
     |
     |--> Object#equals
```

---

So if `equals` is not correctly overridden ([following the `equals` contract rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)), you're not getting the correct behaviour.

Comment: This was so simple to understand. I liked this answer more than the actual code presented here as its explains the reasoning for comparison not working.

Comment: @YogendraJ Thanks a lot :) Happy it helped

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, elements from the `ArrayList` will only be removed if their `equals()` method returns true. The non-overridden method checks for equality based on reference (i.e. they must be the same object in memory).

What you probably want is to override `equals` to be based on the properties of `Member`, such as in the example below:

```
@Override
public void equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (!(o instanceof Member)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ((Member) o).getUserUID().equals(this.userUID) && ((Member) o).getUserName().equals(this.userName);
    }
}
```

In addition, you should override `hashCode()` when overriding `equals()` so that when two objects are equal, they have the same hash code. The non-overriden implementation of hashCode is also based on equality by reference.