# Compare two arraylist and remove common elements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I know this question has been asked many times before. But in my problem there are two arraylist of same object type. Let us say arraylist A contains 5 elements and arraylist B contains  2 elements.

```
Arraylist A elements = obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5

Arraylist B elements = obj1,obj2
```

What I want is I want to remove all the elements of Arraylist A that exist in arraylist B i.e obj1,obj2. Then the final Arraylist A should look like:

```
Arraylist A = obj3,obj4,obj5
```

The code I implemented:

```
for (int i=0;i<arraylistB.size();i++){
    if(arraylistA.contains(arraylistB.get(i))){
        arraylistA.remove(arraylistB.get(i));
        arraylistB.remove(i);
   }
}
```

But this code deleted nothing from `Arraylist A`, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help me!

Comment: did you try [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) ?

Comment: Yes, no success

Comment: What is the type of the elements? Is it a custom type? If so, did you override equals() and hashCode()?

Comment: Yes it is a custom type. No, I did not override equals() and hashcode(). Can you explain what is the function of both?

Comment: Not easily as I’m using my phone. Someone will find a link for a duplicate in a few minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayList removeAll() not removing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960300/arraylist-removeall-not-removing-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to override the `equals()` and `hashcode()`  of class of Object1, Object2 etc which should be instances of the same class.

Then you can do a `removeAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing the elements in arraylistA and arraylistB are not the same, meaning not reference to the same address, so this check is not correct

```
if(arraylistA.contains(arraylistB.get(i)))
```

Should check by e.g. `id` of the element instead.

Comment: Both arraylist have same object type

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: meaning that `obj1` in `arraylistA` and `obj1` in `arraylistB` are different. You can see it by checking both objects addresses via debugging.