# Merging two Java Arraylists with duplicates

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures

I am attempting to generate an ArrayList by merging two other lists. I am allowed duplicate objects, however my resulting ArrayList must contain the difference between both initial lists. I realize this may sound convoluted, so here is an example:

**ArrayList 1:** [obj1, obj1, obj1, obj2, obj4, obj4]
**ArrayList 2:** [obj1, obj2, obj2, obj3]

**Resulting ArrayList:** [obj1, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj4]

I feel like this should be simple but I cannot seem to figure it out. I would use ArrayList1.removeAll(ArrayList2), however each object has its' own individual ID so I don't think I would detect that they are the same object.

EDIT: fixed an error in my resulting ArrayList
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question. If you are having trouble with your homework you should ask you teacher/professor/student aid/etc. That is what they are paid for.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: HInt : This assignment is to test you loops and counter skills :)

Comment: yeah you need to at least have a go. Post some code and maybe someone will give you a hand.

Comment: Not an assignment. I simplified a problem I am having while working on part of a scheduler. The objects are appointments.

Comment: Could you explain the rule to get `List1: obj1, obj1, obj1 and List2: obj1 --> result: obj1, obj1` and `List1: obj2 and List2: obj2, obj2 --> result: no obj2`. What do you mean with `must contain the difference between both initial lists`? Differences on the same index? Objects which are only in one list?

Comment: Basically, it must remove "pairs" between two arrays and the resulting array must include the "unique" elements between both ArrayLists. Therefore, there are 2 instances of obj1 as ArrayList 1 has 2 more than ArrayList 2. As I've mentionned, two instances of an object in this case are considered equal only if they have certain attributes in common. They each have different ID's.

Comment: Is order important? How would `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,3,2,4]` merge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two arrayLists into a new arrayList, with no duplicates and in order, in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917787/merging-two-arraylists-into-a-new-arraylist-with-no-duplicates-and-in-order-in)

Comment: Both initial ArrayLists are already ordered in a way that this would not be an issue. Since they are appointments, they are ordered based on starting time.

Comment: @tobias_k the didn't say that there are order operations defined on those elements, so this question kind of doesn't make sense.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 The question is: Does it matter in what order the elements appear in those "ArrayLists", or would the same result be expected regardless of the order, or if it were two `Map<Object, Integer>` holding just their respective counts?

Comment: Also, since the objects are said to be _not_ equal but just "similar" by some attributes, does it matter _which_ instance of, say, `obj1` are removed/retained?

Comment: @tobias_k oh, ok then.

Comment: @tobias_k, no, it does not matter as the resulting ArrayList will simply be a reference for which appointments need to be created by the factory.

Comment: I still don't understand the desired result. Why does obj1 appear *twice*? Why does obj4 appear *twice*?

Comment: @Marco13 because the answer if union(list1,list2)\intersection(list1,list2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a hashmap, mapping an element to the number of times it occurred in list1, and another hashmap for list2, then make a new arraylist and add objx n times, where n = abs(hashmap1.get(objx) - hashmap2.get(objx)).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4 });
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 2, 3 });
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer i : list1) {
            if (hashMap1.containsKey(i)) {
                hashMap1.put(i, hashMap1.get(i) + 1);
            } else {
                hashMap1.put(i, 1);
            }
        }
        for (Integer i : list2) {
            if (hashMap2.containsKey(i)) {
                hashMap2.put(i, hashMap2.get(i) + 1);
            } else {
                hashMap2.put(i, 1);
            }
        }
        HashSet<Integer> dedup = new HashSet<>();
        for (Integer i : list1) {
            dedup.add(i);
        }
        for (Integer i : list2) {
            dedup.add(i);
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer i : dedup) {
            Integer n1 = hashMap1.get(i);
            Integer n2 = hashMap2.get(i);
            int n = Math.abs((n1 == null ? 0 : n1) - (n2 == null ? 0 : n2));
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                result.add(i);
            }
        }
        for (Integer i : result) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this seems to be what the asker was looking for... Well, two minor remarks: The contents of the first `for` loops may be written more concisely as `hashMap.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);`, and the second ones may be replaced with calls to `dedup.addAll(list);`.

Comment: @Marco13 thanks. You can edit if you want, I'm not familiar with java8 yet.